# Using get_queryset() method in ListView, Django 1.9

Tags: python, html, django, listview, model-view-controller

I've been having difficulty getting ListViews to render as expected on a blog project I'm working on.

I have a Tag model, which is part of a Post model, as follows (from my Post model in models.py):

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    (...)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

TagListView in `views.py` is as follows:

```
class TagListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        try:
            tag = Tag.objects.get(slug=slug)
            return tag.post_set.all()
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            return Post.objects.none()
```

The url's is as follows (which is included in the project like though
`url(r'^blog/?', include('blog.urls')),`, is as follows:

```
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$', TagListView.as_view(
        paginate_by=5,
        model=Tag,
    )),
```

From what I understand, accessing a URL, which, for this example, should be at `localhost:8000/blog/tag/<name-of-tag-here>`, calls TagListView in views.py, which then uses the `get_queryset()` method to generate a ListView of posts featuring a tag with the same slug, which then looks for a template (at `/blog/templates/blog`), which, in the tutorial I'm viewing, is called `tag_post_list.html`, but -- the documentation is unclear on how the ListView finds a template to render and I'm simply following an outdated tutorial.

I'm a bit confused about which variables are being passed into the html template and how to access them. From the results I'm getting it's clear that `get_queryset()` is not actually only returning posts with the same tag listing. [Furthermore, my css isn't rendering, either (which I've made a separate post for)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264531/django-1-9-url-regex-and-listview-not-rendering-html-template-as-expected-temp), despite it being plainly obvious that other tags and elements from my `base.html` file are.

The template begins `{% extends 'base.html' %}` (which is located in `/blog/templates/`) and accesses posts through `{% for post in object_list %}`.  `object_list` obviously does not contain what I think it should, which, as far as I understand, should be due to the the way I'm misusing ListView's `get_queryset()` method.

Thanks.

Comment: There's some debugging missing here. Have you ensured that this view is actually being called? Have you ensured that the slug argument is correct? Is the code going into `get_queryset`? Have you examined what is being returned from that method? You can do all this with the debugger or just by putting in print statements are the relevant points.

Comment: Apart from anything else, this is a list of Posts, not of Tags, so the model should be Post. That wouldn't affect anything, though.

Comment: What does `object_list` actually contain? Nothing? Something else?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I added the class above the line creating the tag column for some clarity. I'm not certain what you mean about the Model.
If you mean the name, maybe there's a better naming convention. I had a simple list of all Posts,chronologically, called PostListView, and this is really PostsByTagName_ListView, but I suppose I was passively accepting the tutorial rather than embracing the wisdom of Uncle Bob.

Comment: @YPCrumble - I'm getting _all_ posts displayed, regardless of the tag.

Comment: @JordonBirk confirm that `tag.post_set.all()` contains all the posts or just the ones with the slug? You would need to set a debugger there and inspect it.

Comment: I meant where you say `model=Tag` in your urls. But nevertheless, as I said you need to do some debugging; as part of that you should cut this down to the very basics. If you go into the shell, get the relevant tag by slug, and then do `tag.post_set.all()`, what do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of questions to unpack here. A couple answers:

Your `ListView` has a `template_name` attribute where you can specify the template to use, like so:

```
class TagListView(ListView):

    template_name = "tag_post_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        try:
            tag = Tag.objects.get(slug=slug)
            return tag.post_set.all()
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            return Post.objects.none()
```

See [this site](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) for a quick list of available attributes for your class based views.

Second answer - you're saying that:

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(slug=slug)
return tag.post_set.all()
```

...in your view isn't actually returning the correct `Post` objects. It's not clear from your code why this is the case. Your view appears correct, though as Daniel Roseman pointed out it should probably be based on the model `Post`, not `Tag`. Overriding the `get_queryset` method to return `Post` objects though means this isn't the offending issue. It's possible that fixing the first issue actually fixes the second, because `object_list` never got called because the template wasn't being called...

Comment: Thanks. The link explains what the documentation is missing.
It appears as though adding `template_name = "tag_post_list.html"` got the results I was looking for, which doesn't actually make much sense to me, now that I think about it.

Now to solve that staticfiles issue.